# How can I achieve this layout with a CoordinatorLayout, EditText, and ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I am switching over to a `CoordinatorLayout` from a `RelativeLayout` so I can take advantage of the FAB and moving with a `Snackbar`. My issue is that I was able to use `layout_below` to give hierarchy and order to the items within my layout. But, when I ran the app with a CoordinatorLayout, everything seems to go haywire and overlap. I tried adding padding, but would rather use layout_below to guarantee that everything will function 100%.

[image: What it looked like with RelativeLayout prior][image: What it looks like with CoordinatorLayout]

And wrapping some elements in a `RelativeLayout` doesn't seem to help at all.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusedByDefault="true"
            android:hint="@string/input_a_number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoPersonalizedLearning"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_gap"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minWidth="180dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearParent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    [![<!--        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"-->][1]][1]

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/jade_fab"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/jade" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your xml file with this layout file. It should do the job!

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusedByDefault="true"
            android:hint="@string/input_a_number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoPersonalizedLearning"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_gap"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minWidth="180dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearParent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/jade_fab"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/jade" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the issue or what you changed?

Comment: I wrap the edit text view and listview in the vertical Linear layout so that It shows list view blow the edittext view.
Is that work for you?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.